# How to order this JSON response by AM/PM time property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

I have a JSON Object like below,

```
{
10-AM: {
...
},
10-PM: {
....
},
11-AM: {
....
},
11-PM: {
....
}
}
```

Requirement here is that I need to order by 12 hours time based and to make,

```
{
10-AM: {
...
},
11-AM: {
....
},
10-PM: {
....
},
11-PM: {
....
}
}
```

Since i tried with different different logics, but not able to get prperly. Is there any way to get result in order?

Comment: This is an object, you can't guarantee the order, use array instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this function:

```js
const times = {
  "10-AM": { time: "its 10 am" },
  "07-PM": { time: "its 7 pm" },
  "11-AM": { time: "its 11 am" },
  "09-PM": { time: "its 9 pm" },
  "12-PM": { time: "its 12 pm"  },
  "10-PM": { time: "its 10 pm" },
  "01-AM": { time: "its 1 am" },
  "11-PM": { time: "its 11 pm"  }
}

const sortTimes = (times) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(times)
  const am = keys.filter(key => key.indexOf("AM") > 0)
  const pm = keys.filter(key => key.indexOf("PM") > 0)
  const sorted = [...am.sort(), ...pm.sort()]
  const sortedObject = {}
  for (let i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++ ) {
    sortedObject[sorted[i]] = times[sorted[i]]
  }

  return sortedObject
}

console.log(sortTimes(times))
```

Answer (score 1):

As @gorak remarked quite rightly, you cannot guarantee an order of properties in an object. So you should be aiming for an array of objects instead. In the 12-hour clock system there is an anomaly regarding the time "12 p. m.": A time like 12:15 p. m. is equivalent to 00:15h on the 24-hour clock and marks a time in the *first hour* of a day. So, if your hourly intervals refer to the hour *following* the given time you need to make provisions for that: i. e.: 12 p. m. becomes "0 a. m.". Nobody would write it like that, but that is the way any algorithm can sort it without problems.

```js
const times = {
  "10-AM": { time: "it's 10 am" },
  "07-PM": { time: "it's 7 pm" },
  "11-AM": { time: "it's 11 am" },
  "09-PM": { time: "it's 9 pm" },
  "12-PM": { time: "it's 12 pm"  },
  "10-PM": { time: "it's 10 pm" },
  "01-AM": { time: "it's 1 am" },
  "11-PM": { time: "it's 11 pm"  }
}

const keys=Object.keys(times).map(k=>{
  let srt=k.substr(3)+k.substr(0,2)
  if (srt=="PM12") srt="AM00";
  return {k,srt}; })
.sort((a,b)=>a.srt.localeCompare(b.srt)).map(k=>k.k);  
// now we have the keys in an ordered array:
console.log(keys)
// and can list the times object with it
keys.forEach(k=>console.log(k+':'+times[k].time))
// or you can generate a sorted array of objects:
let sorted=keys.map(k=>times[k]);
console.log(sorted);
```